# C++ WINAPI window does not refresh

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a simple window inside a thread that is created by an injected `DLL`. This is how my thread looks like:

```
int Thread()
{
  HWND hwnd;
  MSG messages;
  WNDCLASSEX wincl;
  /* The Window structure */
  wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
  wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
  wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
  wincl.style = CS_CLASSDC;
  wincl.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
  wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
  wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
  wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
  wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;
  wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;
  wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;

  wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_BACKGROUND;
  if (!RegisterClassEx(&wincl))
    ;

  hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    0,
    szClassName,
    "Windows App",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    544,
    375,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hThisInstance,
    NULL
    );
  ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);

  while (true) {
    if (GetMessage(&messages, NULL, 0, 0)) {
      TranslateMessage(&messages);
      DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }
    SetWindowText(hwnd, b);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);

    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    RedrawWindow(hwnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_UPDATENOW);

    //do the stuff that computes values to show
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And this is my window procedure:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch (message)
  {
  case WM_PAINT:
  {

    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    TextOut(hdc,
      10,
      10,
      b,
      50);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    return 0L;
  }
  break;
  case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
  default:
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The window works, but there is a major problem. I want the values to be updated and displayed in real time, be it in the title bar or inside the window. And despite using these 3 functions inside a loop: `ShowWindow`, `UpdateWindow`, `RedrawWindow`, the redrawing doesn't work as I wish it would. When I'm working with an application that is being injected into and generating the value I want to be displayed in my created window, neither the title bar or main area of my window update. But when the desired value changes and I move the mouse over my window, the title bar does update. As for the main area, it updates ONLY when I drag the window to the edge of the screen so that I cover the place where the text is to be displayed and then uncover it (it can even repaint partially), or just minimize and restore the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if (GetMessage(&messages, NULL, 0, 0)) {
   TranslateMessage(&messages);
   DispatchMessage(&messages);
 }
 SetWindowText(hwnd, b);
 ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);

 UpdateWindow(hwnd);
 RedrawWindow(hwnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_UPDATENOW);
```

GetMessage **blocks** if there are no messages for it to process.
You should either ensure that it has messages to process, perhaps by using SetTimer to gerate timer messages, or look into using PeekMessage instead of GetMessage (With the PM_REMOVE flag)

Comment: Thank you, PeekMessage is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Call `InvalidateRect` before `UpdateWindow`.

Comment: Thank you, now my value inside the main area behaves exactly like the title bar - it refreshes upon mouse mouse movement, even if the window is inactive. But I want it to refresh without any interaction.

Comment: See `SetTimer` API. It will send `WM_TIMER` message at specified time - you will call `InvalidateRect` there (`UpdateWindow` is not necessary).

Comment: I don't see how it could help me, since I'm calling InvalidateRect all the time already and this doesn't bother me.  I've just found kind of a workaround - calling SetForegroundWindow alongsite the updating functions. But it's not very elegant and convenient.